# Regular Expression positive lookbehind

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regex, that allowes the following patterns:

```
1234
1234567
123456789
12345678900-
12345678900-123456
```

It should be possible to only insert numbers and only one hyphen is allowed.

I tried with the following regex:

```
^[0-9]{1,11}(?(?<=\d{11})[-]?|)[0-9]{6}
```

It should not be possible to have 11 characters without the hyphen at the end(12345678900 is wrong).

Unfortunatly it didnt work as I intended.

Comment: Just to be clear: The hyphen can **not** occur before the the 12th digit? Also, is there always six *or* zero digits after the hyphen? For example, is `1-1` allowed? or `1-`?

Comment: yes the hyphen has to be the 12th digit

Comment: there is always six or zero digits after the hyphen and 1-1 and 1- is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You can match 1-10 digit and optionally match 1 digit followed by `-` and 6 digits.

```
^\d{1,10}(?:\d?-(?:\d{6})?)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{1,10}` Match 1-10 digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d?-` Match a single optional digit and `-`
  - `(?:\d{6})?` Match optional 6 digits
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QsNj7v/1)

Another variation could be matching 1-10 digits or match 11 digits with a hyphen and optionally 6 digits if the hyphen should only possible after 11 digits.

```
^(?:\d{1,10}|\d{11}-(?:\d{6})?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sikDag/1)

Comment: @JvdV Yes, that looks better indeed. This should also match `12345678900-`

Comment: I tried to ask OP if he would want to allow for something like `1-123456` but that could still be a case you need to cover.

Comment: @JvdV Yes, that is why I added the second pattern.

Comment: Ok, does that match `1-123456`?

Comment: @JvdV No, the hyphen will be only matched after 11 digits, as I see this part in the OP's pattern `(?<=\d{11})[-]?` Lets hope we will find out soon enough :-)

Comment: Yeah I was personally thinking `^\d{1,10}(?:\d?-(?:\d{6})?)?$` ticks all the boxes but a littel more information is needed =).

Comment: @JvdV Ow yes, or else the minimum amount of digits is 2 :-)  as I have now

Comment: Thank you very much guys! the regex works perfektly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
^[0-9]{1,11}(?:(?<=[0-9]{11})-(?:[0-9]{6})?)?$
^\d{1,11}(?:(?<=\d{11})-(?:\d{6})?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FH8vHy/3). Using `\d` is possible in case it matches ASCII digits in your regex flavor or you do not care if `\d` matches all possible Unicode digit chars or not.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{1,11}` - one to eleven digits
- `(?:(?<=[0-9]{11})-(?:[0-9]{6})?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `(?<=[0-9]{11})` - immediately to the left there must be 11 digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `(?:[0-9]{6})?` - an optional occurrence of six digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: FYI: If the regex is used for live input validation, a `^[0-9]{1,11}(?:(?<=[0-9]{11})-(?:[0-9]{0,6})?)?$` pattern can be used, the only difference is that it will allow zero to six digits after `-` till end of string.